# Can we use foreign key as primary key along with another attribute as below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to create this project for one of my assignments and I have to use Transact-SQL to create this database. I have changed this below code many times to avoid this error but its still keep coming and can't think of any reason for this.

```
CREATE TABLE Job 
(
    Job_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (500, 1),
    Pickup_Address VARCHAR(255),
    Destination_Address VARCHAR(255),
    Crew_Name VARCHAR(255),
    Customer_Name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(Job_ID)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Job(Pickup_Address,Destination_Address,Crew_Name,Customer_Name)
VALUES ('Ceylinco Centre Building, 3rd Floor, Nawam Mawatha','NO.50, Sumanagala Road,Rathmalana','Maharagama Crew 1','Dilan'),
       ('3/82, ST.JUDE LANE,Dalugama','19A, 4th Lane,Koswatthe Rd','Maharagama Crew 2','Kasun'),
       ('19 Saunders Place,Colombo 12','54/3, Elapitiwala,Ragama','Kottawa Crew 1','Kelly'),
       ('381 Prince of Wales Avenue,Colombo 14','51, SEA STREET,Colombo','Kottawa Crew 2','Kasun'),
       ('250 Galle Road,Colombo 03','34, Pepiliyana Road,Nugegoda','Nugegoda Crew 2','Alan')
GO

CREATE TABLE Loads 
(
    Load_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Job_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Job(Job_ID),
    Load_Type VARCHAR(255),
    Product_Name VARCHAR(255),
    Loaded_Time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    PRIMARY KEY (Load_ID, Job_ID),
)
GO
```

I have executed the above SQL code, previously I couldn't create the `Loads` table and got an error

> Invalid referencing table

After I tried to avoid this now it can be executed although there is an error and it's in below. what I need to know is the reason for this and will it be a problem if I keep this as it is. Thank you

> Foreign key 'FK_Loads_c6b32eef601ef719ed3' References invalid table 'job'

Comment: Your script runs OK for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b7ac46b67b4c7fba791b58f6ad98bbb

Comment: A question about the table `Loads`, why should `Job_ID` be part of the primary key. In my opinion, that doesn't make sense, since `Load_ID` is unique in itself. I also see a TYPO when creating the Loads table, the comma after `PRIMARY KEY (Load_ID, Job_ID),` does not belong there.

Comment: Probably if this is a staging table, then why bother with a primary key at all. Looks like it should have Job_Id *first* since this is how you will join on it, I would just create a unique clustered index on `loads` on `Job_Id, Load_Id`

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive database collation? The code example calls the table `Job` with an uppercase `J` but the error message says, `References invalid table 'job'` with a lowercase `j`.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, you may have the case sensitive collation. To know the collation you can run this code:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation');
```

If this is the case, you can change it (2008 or higher, except azure) with code like the following (adding the desired collation):

```
ALTER DATABASE YOURS_DATABASE
COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CS_AS ;
```

more information here [here](http://more%20information%20at%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15)